# Understanding try and except with __builtin__

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, try-catch

New to Python and have yet to use or come across `__builtin__` and was curious about what the following code is actually doing:

```
import sys

try:
    import __builtin__
    input = getattr(__builtin__, 'raw_input')
except (ImportError, AttributeError):
    pass

username = input("username: ")
password = input("password: ")
```

Is this code being used to basically check whether or not the script is being run  with Python 2 or Python 3 and if it's Python 2, `input()` is converted to `raw_input()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather poorly-written code to make `input()` refer to `raw_input()` if the latter exists.  That makes it compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3.  A simpler way to do it would be this:

```
try:
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    pass

username = input("username: ")
password = input("password: ")
```

The [`__builtin__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) module is the module where all the builtin objects like `input()` and `raw_input()` live.  But we don't need it in this case.  In Python 3.x, this is called [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html), which is why the author of this code is catching `ImportError`.

If you need to do this kind of thing *in general*, it's a good idea to use [`six`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) rather than coding all these things by hand.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Could you explain or expound a bit more on why the code I posted is poorly written exactly? Is it overly complicated for what it's intending to do?

Comment: @Malvin9000: Yes, very.  There is no need to import `__builtin__` (see answer), no need to use `getattr()` if you do the import (just write `__builtin__.raw_input`), and no need to catch `AttributeError` (3.x will raise `ImportError` before you get to that point).